# Digit wise modulo for calculating power function for very very large positive integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, modulo, number-theory

Hi I am writing a code to calculate P^Q where

```
P, Q are positive integers which can have number of digits upto 100000
```

I want the result as

```
result = (P^Q)modulo(10^9+7)
```

Example:

```
P = 34534985349875439875439875349875 
Q = 93475349759384754395743975349573495
Answer = 735851262
```

I tried using the trick:

```
 (P^Q)modulo(10^9+7) = (P*P*...(Q times))modulo(10^9+7)

 (P*P*...(Q times))modulo(10^9+7) = ((Pmodulo(10^9+7))*(Pmodulo(10^9+7))...(Q times))modulo(10^9+7)
```

Since both P and Q are very large, I should store them in an array and do modulo digit by digit.

Is there any efficient way of doing this or some number theory algorithm which I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might be interested in [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: If you decide to store on array, you can use BCD encoding for memory save.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. It looks interesting but as the number (10^9) is a prime number and this problem involves a prime modulus, I have a gut feeling that there is some number theory theorem which I forgot might help here. I am searching for some number theory trick as this question is more about math trick and less about programming paradigm.

Comment: Then maybe you should as on http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for pointing out. I was not aware of this. I have posted this question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rather efficient way:

1)Compute p1 = P modulo 10^9 + 7

2)Compute q1 = Q modulo 10^9 + 6

3)Then P^Q modulo 10^9 + 7 is equal to p1^q1 modulo 10^9 + 7. This equality is true because of Fermat's little theorem. Note that p1 and q1 are small enough to fit in 32-bit integer, so you can implement binary exponention with standard integer type(for intermidiate computations, 64-bit integer type is sufficient because initial values fit in 32-bits).

Comment: yea Fermat's little guy