# Binary Search Tree questions and Data Structure questions.

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, frequency

I have a couple of questions that I need help answering. I am currently using C++ in a data structure class. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

1. How could you count the frequency of a number in a binary search tree?
2. How could you tell if 2 binary search trees contained exactly the same numbers?
3. Could we make a template class for binary search trees? Why or why not?
4. Convert 23415 in base 7 to base 5, using the digit-wise algorithm
5. Tell me 2 big differences between a copy constructor and an assignment operator (operator =). Justify your answers.

Comment: Looks like homework. What did you tried ?

Comment: Normally it's 1 question per post :-) . You need a tutotial on binary search tree ? May be you can find that online.

Comment: Look this question(s) is(are) _too broooooooooooooooad_!

Answer (score 3):

1. With utmost care and finesse.
2. I would tell it like it is.
3. Depends on who you mean by "we".
4. Done. Did you mean to ask a question?
5. -

   ```
       One performs a copy,
   the other an assingment.
      One is a constructor,
     the other an operator.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the links which can help you with the answer: 
(It would be too long to paste solution here)

**1.** **How could you count the frequency of a number in a binary search tree?**

> Visit below for tree traversal technique. While traversing just
>   increment a counter (starting from        0) whenever you find your
>   number.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/618/

**2. How could you tell if 2 binary search trees contained exactly the same numbers?**

> Check below link. It says equal, so I am not sure if this might help
>   you, but surely can give you can idea

[Determine if two binary trees are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482822/determine-if-two-binary-trees-are-equal)

**3. Could we make a template class for binary search trees? Why or why not?**

> Certainly we can. Templates are made for keeping things generic. BST
>   can hold any data - Char, int, long anything even your own data type.
>   So this data type can be used in Template class object creation and
>   class can be defined as class BST. Let me know if you need further
>   help on this

**4. Convert 23415 in base 7 to base 5, using the digit-wise algorithm**

> [Digit-Wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117346/digit-wise-modulo-for-calculating-power-function-for-very-very-large-positive-in) algorithm is used to calculate a power of a number.
>   and while converting numbers to different bases, we need to add number
>   in base^digit fashion. So, there isnt a problem. Refer the link I have
>   given for implementation of Digit-Wise algoritm. Then use that function on
>   each digit of number giving num as 'base' and power as 'digit'

**5. Tell me 2 big differences between a copy constructor and an assignment operator (operator =). Justify your answers.**

> Well I remember that from my undergrad course :) But I am, too lazy to
>   write here. So refer below

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-vs-assignment-operator-in-c/

Comment: Thank you guys very much for getting back to me and giving me some sites to look at to help me out!

Comment: @Steven Pleasure ! If you think my answer helped you, you can upvote and accept it as answer so that others can be benefited too